# Excel Find Replace columns

Tags: excel

Im not familiar with excel formula. I need something like find and replace.

I have excel with the following data.

```
A   B                       C               D

1   Retainer                AMKOR           Assessment
2   Assessment              ARROW           Retainer
3   Registration            Aerospace       Compliance 
4   Capital                 CONTINENTAL     Change
5   Change                  DELL            Capital
6   Compliance              Dow Chemical    Registration
```

I want to replace the column D with the column A value.

The result should be something like this.

```
A   B                       C               D

1   Retainer                AMKOR           2
2   Assessment              ARROW           1
3   Registration            Aerospace       6
4   Capital                 CONTINENTAL     5
5   Change                  DELL            4
6   Compliance              Dow Chemical    3
```

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` will do it if you switch Cols A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIND/REPLACE would be relatively tedious as each instance would need to be treated separately. Instead I suggest, in E3 and copied down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D3,B:B,0))
```

Then copy ColumE, Paste Special..., Values over the top and delete ColumnD.